# useEffect not running on Vercel deployment using Vite and React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-hooks, vercel

I have deployed a React site using Vite as the framework through Vercel, the project uses React Router for routing and everything works fine on my local machine, I configured the backend on a separate service and it works/responds to requests just fine.

When I was testing the Vercel deployment however, none of the useEffects hooks were running, everything else worked fine and the requests were firing as normal.

I believe it has something to do with React-Router, this is my vercel.json config file:

```json
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

This makes the routing/redirecting work, and this is one of the useEffect hooks:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  return async () => {
    const entries = await fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/entries/list` } });
    if (!entries) return;
    const jsonData = await entries.json();
    setEntries(jsonData.profiles);
  }
}, []);
```

What steps should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the issue here is that your `useEffect` hook is only returning a cleanup function. Since the `useEffect` has an empty dependency array (`[]`) this means the effect runs at the end of the initial render cycle, and then finally when the component unmounts, the cleanup function will run and fetch the data.

*In other words, the effect is running, but your logic isn't executed until the component unmounts.*

I suspect you meant to initiate this fetch in the effect and update some local `entries` state with the fetched profile data. Instead of returning a function from the hook callback just declare the fetching function in scope and invoke it so the logic is executed while the component is still mounted.

Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProfiles = async () => {
    try {
      const entries = await fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/entries/list`);
      if (!entries) return;
      const jsonData = await entries.json();
      setEntries(jsonData.profiles);
    } catch(e) {
      // handle/ignore any errors or rejected Promises
    }
  };

  fetchProfiles(); // <-- call "on mount"
}, []);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'm surprised I haven't considered this! Thanks for the great explanation!